# java selenium cant find iframe path

Tags: java, selenium, testing, iframe, automation

i'm trying to get into iframe, but i get error like this:

```
Find element :By.id: fullscreen-app-host
Find element :By.id: fullscreen-app-host
Get Exception: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#fullscreen\-app\-host"}
```

and here is iframe css:

```
<iframe class="publishedAppIframe" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="false" id="fullscreen-app-host" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" name="fullscreen-app-host" allow="geolocation; microphone; camera; fullscreen" style="" title="holidays" cd_frame_id_="6a1f85c52ae"></iframe>
```

i have tryied many different ways, but result always almost the same - can't find element into iframe.

here i paste link to code of methods i use:
https://www.codepile.net/pile/7eygVLY3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**your code:**

```
public void selectIframe() {
        String parent = driver.getWindowHandle();
        for (String childHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
            if (!childHandle.equals(parent)) {
                driver.switchTo().frame(childHandle);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Problem:**

Iframes are not window , its an element you cannot use :

```
 driver.switchTo().frame(childHandle);
```

if you want to switch to window then use:

```
driver.switchTo().window(childHandle);
```

if you want to switch iframe , then find that iframe and then switch to it

eg :

```
frame = driver.findElement(By.TAGNAME("iframe"));
driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
```

Comment: your example looks the same like this: driver.switchTo().frame(findElementByXpath(By.id("fullscreen-app-host"))); or i am wrong?

Comment: @Jetz i don't know what you meant,  the syntax foer switch_to().frame() is switch_to().frame(index/webelement) . the frame method expects a webelement , frame name (the value of name attribute) or index. Not windows handle

Comment: @Jetz https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html?highlight=switch_to#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to

Comment: updated it to java code , thiought the question was python related. : https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#frame(int)

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#switchTo()